# How do i properly my note file from internal storage

Tags: java, android

I am working on a note application that displays item in a list view. I intend to delete list view item from context menu selection. So far, i am able to delete list view item. However, when the file refuses to get deleted from phone internal storage as the deleted list view item keeps coming back when i close the app and re-open. 
How do i get round this? Her is my code.

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
        final AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
      final  Note mLoadedNote = (Note) mListNotes.getAdapter().getItem(info.position);
        mLoadedNote.getTitle();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.delete:
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Delete " +  mLoadedNote.getTitle())
                        .setMessage("are you sure?")
                .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(mLoadedNote != null ) {
                        File file = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
    // doesnt work for me                 if (file.exists()) {
                         file.delete();
                     }
                        ArrayAdapter<Note> arrayAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<Note>) mListNotes.getAdapter();
arrayAdapter.remove(arrayAdapter.getItem(info.position));
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  mLoadedNote.getTitle() + " is deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  "can not delete the note '" + mLoadedNote.getTitle() + "'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
                })
                    .setNegativeButton("NO", null); //do nothing on clicking NO button :P
                alertDialog.show();
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: ok. thanks for the info. can you answer me now?